# What is the lookup time complexity of a theoretical truly unbounded-size hashset?

Tags: algorithm, physics

I know that on a single machine, hashset lookup time is quoted as O(1). In real-world distributed hashsets, it'll be O(logn) or similar since there's a hierarchy of nodes. Disclaimer, probably none of the rest of this question is applicable to real life, as we're going beyond the buzzwords "web scale," "planet scale," "interplanetary..." it's universe-scale now.

Say we're considering truly unbounded number of fixed-size keys, and we're going to build whatever hardware is needed to support that. To help visualize this, I'm describing a system with today's computing terms. The hashset lookup always has to start at the same physical point, let's say it's the user's terminal. The set is composed of many machines, as tightly packed together as possible in a filled spherical formation around the terminal. Given a key, each machine can either tell you whether it's in the set or tell you which machine directly connected to it, and further out into the sphere, to ask. So you start from the core and follow a path to the surface. You could also think of this as an IP network, since distributed hashset lookups are like IP routing. OR you could think of this as memory lookup in one machine with tons of RAM and caches packed as efficiently as possible.

I'm guessing in the end, we're limited by two things I'm assuming to be constant here: how densely we can pack the machines, and the speed of light. Due to the first, the number of keys we can store is proportional to the volume of our system. If the lookup time is limited by our constant speed of light, we need to consider the radius of the sphere, which is proportional to the cube root of the volume, so we have **O(cube root)** lookup time. Multiply our set size by 8, and the volume is multiplied by 8, so the radius is multiplied by 2.

But maybe each machine's memory is dense enough that it can point to way more machines than are possible to fit one layer out into the sphere (definitely true with today's general-purpose machines but idk about something totally built for this purpose), and you'd get a logarithmic lookup time complexity by intentionally making the sphere sparser. This is where my brain melts. Anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: The whole point of big-O notation is to tell you how the algorithm responds to changes in the size of its input.  O(1) means the size has no effect on the time, and that applies to universe-size data sets.

Comment: The system you're describing isn't a hashset, it's a distributed database, and I don't think anybody claims one of those will be O(1) - although Google gets close.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't mean it's the size of the entire universe, but even if it is, many say that's not fixed in size.

Re other comment, Wikipedia and other sources mention "distributed hash tables," and hashsets reduce to hashtables, so I figured it counted.

Comment: I don't understand a "truly unbounded number of fixed-size keys". A set of fixed-size keys is finite.

Comment: Seems to be a candidate for https://cs.stackexchange.com/